# regex matching with special characters metacharacters

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I am trying to match certain strings and while I have to escape some special characters it still isn't matching correctly.

I have this

```
 var first=/.+?(?=\[)/i
```

which still matches the whole string which needs to only match up to the first [

this is the string  business[account]

I need to match business then match account as well. It is for a plugin that be used to get the object notations with these later. Every element has a different attribute.

Comment: Try `.match(/(\w+)\[(\w+)\]/)` to extract both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something this simple, a lookahead isn't really necessary. Try using a character class like this:

```
var first = /[^[]+/
```

This will match one or more of any character *other than* `[`.

If you'd like to work this into a regex that can match both parts of a string like `"business[account]"`, try this:

```
/([^[]+)\[([^\]]+)\]/
```

This will match one or more of any character *other than* `[`, captured in group 1, followed by a `[`, followed by one or more of any character *other than* `]`, captured in group 2, followed by `]`.

E.g.

```
console.log(/([^[]+)\[([^\]]+)\]/.exec("business[account]"));
// ["business[account]", "business", "account"]
```

Comment: Close very close expect it still grabs the last ]

Comment: Ok I like this one. Though I don't like the output. ["extend[me]", "extend", "me", index: 0 , input: "extend[me]]

Comment: @EasyBB what don't you like about it? is there something wrong with the output?

Comment: Just too much I suppose I'm upvoting still thank you.

Comment: @EasyBB The `exec` function will return an array with several elements. element 0 will be the entire matched string, 1 will be the first group, 2 will be the second group, and so on. You can just ignore the first element if you don't need it, or even [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) it out.

Comment: I'm using match function should I use exec or what. Yeah I'm debating on which to use yours or phihag as his is more simple. Though in the sense it is same just one uses the lazy operators

Comment: Either `match` or `exec` will work. In both cases you have to ignore the first element. Which pattern you pick is up to you and your precise needs, but they are not *entirely* equal. See what happens when you try it with a string like `"extend[][me]"`.

Comment: The code will be never be like that as the data attribute is entered dynamically which I set with a code. Though you are right both are different in their entirety

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there; just add groups (with parentheses) to match what you want:

```
var m = /(.+?)\[(.+?)\]/.exec("business[account]");
console.log("variable: " + m[1], "index: " + m[2]);
```

Comment: I get an unterminated group

Comment: @EasyBB Make sure you don't have a typo somewhere. [Here is an online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hcSmf/)

Comment: Ok great I don't know why but it works now. Though should I be using the lazy operators or should I use the regex from p.s.w.g

Comment: Oh thanks for editing ;) not sure if it make the code syntax correct in my op as like I said I am on my phone haha